# Extra space after self-defined environment

Tags: spacing, environments

I defined a new environment `eq` to simplify the `equation`,

```
\newenvironment{eq}{\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}
```

It works, but it seems that there is a extra space at the end of the environment, which can be tested as in the following command:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{eq}
a+b=c
\end{eq}
There is a extra space at the end of ``eq'' environment.

\begin{eq}
a+b=c
\end{eq}%
NO extra space exists at the end of ``eq'' environment.
\end{document}
```

My question is how to delete the extra space automatically?

Comment: The command `\ignorespacesafterend` works for me, why you delete the comments?

Comment: I have added an answer, that is why :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding definining wrapper environments for other environments, it is better to use the 'real' commands for the environment begin and end macros, i.e. `\equation` and `\endequation` in this example and add the trailing `%` characters at the right position.

The question is rather, whether is is useful to do such short wrappers at all;-)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newenvironment{eq}{%
  \equation%
  }{%
  \endequation%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{eq}
a+b=c
\end{eq}
\textbf{Now} there is \textbf{no}  extra space at the end of ``eq'' environment.

\begin{eq}
a+b=c
\end{eq}%
NO extra space exists at the end of ``eq'' environment.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems that `\newenvironment{eq}{\equation}{\endequation}` works!

Comment: But why `\newenvironment{abst}{\abstract}{\endabstract}` can't work?

Comment: @user19832: A short test for `abst` works. One has to be careful with environments with has arguments, of course, but this not the case for `abstract`, as far as I know

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why you want to do this but add `\ignorespacesafterend` as in

```
{\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newenvironment{eq}{\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
\begin{eq}
a+b=c
\end{eq}
There is a extra space at the end of ``eq'' environment.
%  <---------- and don't leave a blank line here as a good practice
\begin{eq}
a+b=c
\end{eq}%
NO extra space exists at the end of ``eq'' environment.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version using `environ` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{eq}{%
\begin{equation}
\BODY
\end{equation}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{eq}
a+b=c
\end{eq}
There is a extra space at the end of ``eq'' environment.
%  and don't leave a blank line here as a good practice
\begin{eq}
a+b=c
\end{eq}%
NO extra space exists at the end of ``eq'' environment.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, `\let\eq\equation\let\endeq\endequation` is even easier, isn't it? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg For me `\begin{equation}... \end{equation}` is the easiest :P